# What happens behind the PHP pcntl_fork()?

Tags: php, pcntl

I have spend hours, days, weeks trying to understand how PHP pcntl really works and still dont know exactly what is really happening.

**Why parents and childs ?** I am using Debian (am far for being an expert in computers I must admit) but all I want to do is receive a message from my webSocket client (which I have already managed to do) and keep listening other users.

In other words, if I receive a message and use a `sleep(5);` then the server will not listen any other messages until this piece of code is finished.

*Note that the `sleep(5)` is for test purposes. I plan to process hundreds of messages simultaneously and thats why am trying to figure out how could `pcntl` be helpfull.*

```
$pid = pcntl_fork();

echo "start\n";

if($pid) {
  // parent process runs what is here
  echo "parent\n";
}
else {
  // child process runs what is here
  echo "child\n";
}

echo "end\n";
```

What exactly is happening **behind the above script ?** Why am I getting this result ?

> start
>
> parent
>
> end
>
> start
>
> child
>
> end

Could someone please explain me **what is the computer "thinking" ?**

Comment: After the `pcntl_fork` line the interpreter creates another process with the copy of current memory and then they both continue execution from the very same line in parallel.

Comment: current memory = ? you mean from `echo "start\n";` to end of this script?

Comment: no, the state of the current memory. Variables, stack, etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basically what happens:

```
                    pcntl_fork()
                       ||
      +----------------++------------------+
    parent                               child

    "start"                              ...
    "parent"                             ...
    "end"                                ...
                                         "start"
                                         "child"
                                         "end"
```

Any code after `pcntl_fork()` gets executed by both parent *and* child process; you can think of the child as a clone of the parent, except that the outcome of `pcntl_fork()` is `0`; it's like the code enters a different reality, not unlike Back to the future ;-)

This is just one of the possible outcomes, though; depending on cpu usage, the child's "start" may occur together with the parent's "parent" output.

Comment: so I can run an infinite loop (my websocket) inside parent, and call as many child processes I want ? (the message's interpreter)

Comment: @JackM. Yes, you can spawn as many (within limits) child processes as you like; note that you should reap the child processes that have stopped; see also [`pcntl_wait()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-wait.php)

Comment: Ok it is working :) But why do I need to suspend the process until child has exited? I need these childs to run independently from everything else.

Comment: @JackM. You don't have to suspend the parent; you can check using `WNOHANG` option or listen for SIGCHLD signals that the OS sends.